# SQL: Employee, Manager, City Names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am super new to SQL, but hoping for some input on the below. In this assignment, we aren't supposed to use PK or FK so everything is cross referenced. I have an EMPLOYEE table with a column for Manager ID as the Employee ID, and a CityID which is referenced to the City table which includes the ID and Name.

I need to pull up the Employee's name, employee's city, manager name and the managers city, the issue I am having is, one the manager has a NULL value in the City, so it is not producing all of the possible results. If there is a NULL value in any of the columns, I want it to show NULL.

Any idea what I could add to allow for NULL values?

Here is the query so far:

SELECT
CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS 'EmployeeName', c.CityName AS 'EmployeeCity',
CONCAT(m.FirstName, ' ', m.LastName) AS 'ManagerName', ci.CityName AS 'ManagerCity'

FROM
EMPLOYEE e

JOIN
EMPLOYEE m
ON e.ManagerID = m.EmployeeID

JOIN
CITY c
ON e.CityID = c.CityID

JOIN
CITY ci
ON m.CityID = ci.CityID;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` returns all rows from tables where the key record of one table is equal to the key records of another table
`INNER JOIN` returns only matching tuples/rows if there is a much on the right of he compared tables. 
While `LEFT OUTER JOIN` returns all matching tuples/rows from both compared tables.

I recommend that you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your case.

Comment: Perfect, please mark it as accepted answer when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just use `concat_ws()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', e.FirstName,  e.LastName) AS EmployeeName, 
       c.CityName AS EmployeeCity,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', m.FirstName, m.LastName) AS ManagerName, 
       ci.CityName AS ManagerCity
```

`CONCAT_WS()` ignores `NULL` values.  And as a bonus, won't include the space.

Note:  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names.

Answer (score 0):

@casscode you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in your query, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS 'EmployeeName', 
    c.CityName AS 'EmployeeCity', 
    CONCAT(m.FirstName, ' ', m.LastName) AS 'ManagerName',   
    ci.CityName AS 'ManagerCity'
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN EMPLOYEE m ON e.ManagerId = m.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN CITY c ON e.CityId = c.CityId
LEFT JOIN CITY ci ON m.CityId = ci.CityId;
```